# How to refer to a variable name with spaces in Python?

Tags: python

How would I deal with this?  The variable "residual sugar" has a space, other than don't use variables with spaces (not my data).

```
plt.plot(trimmedWine.density, trimmedWine.residual sugar, 'bo', alpha=.25)
```

Comment: That's not a variable.

Comment: I know it is a very old question, but if, like me, you are looking for the correct answer to that question ("how to refer to a variable name with spaces in Python", note that there is no mention of Panda anywhere, hence not a duplicate), the solution is to use `locals()['my variable']` or `globals()['my variable']`. If you want to refer to an object's property, you should use `getattr(obj, 'my property')` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to pandas data frame column, if so, then trimmedWine['residual sugar'] is what you probably need.